# function breaking after running it once

Tags: javascript, html, function

I want to create a matrix calculator with addition and subtraction. I made it so I can input the column and row count. It works except after one function activation it stops recognizing the functions as if they weren't there. I'm suspecting something with the `this` keyword but I'm not sure what. Here's a code snippet (use full page):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <style>
            * {
                font-family: 'Comic Sans MS'
            }
            input::-webkit-outer-spin-button,
            input::-webkit-inner-spin-button {
                -webkit-appearance: none;
                margin: 0;
            }
            input {
                font-size: 50px;
                text-align: center;
                width: 96px;
                height: 96px;
                border: 2px solid black;
                margin: 0px;
                padding: 0px;
            }
            div {
                position: absolute;
                border: 2px solid black;
                border-radius: 5px;
                width: 300px;
                height: 200px;
                display: flex;
                align-items: center;
                justify-content: space-between;
                flex-wrap: wrap;
            }
            #d1 {
                top: 25px;
                left: 25px;
            }
            #d2 {
                top: 25px;
                right: 25px;
            }
            #o {
                position: absolute;
                top: 500px;
                left: 25px;
                align: center;
            }
            button {
                position: absolute;
                border: 4px solid black;
                font-size: 50px;
                top: 300px;
                left: 25px;
                width: 100px;
                height: 100px;
                background-color: transparent;
                border-radius: 5px;
            }
            #add {
                left: 25px;
            }
            #sub {
                left: 150px;
            }
            p {
                position: absolute;
                border: 2px solid black;
                padding: 5px;
                border-radius: 10px;
                width: 160px;
                top: 25px;
                left: 40%;
                font-size: 25px;
                display: flex;
                align-items: center;
                flex-wrap: wrap;
                justify-content: space-between;
            }
            #r, #c {
                border: 1px solid black;
                border-radius: 5px;
                height: 25px;
                width: 50px;
                font-size: 20px
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="d1">
            <input type="number" id="a1">
            <input type="number" id="a2">
            <input type="number" id="a3">
            <input type="number" id="a4">
            <input type="number" id="a5">
            <input type="number" id="a6">
        </div>
        <div id="d2">
            <input type="number" id="b1">
            <input type="number" id="b2">
            <input type="number" id="b3">
            <input type="number" id="b4">
            <input type="number" id="b5">
            <input type="number" id="b6">
        </div>
        <button onclick="add()" id="add">+</button>
        <button onclick="sub()" id="sub">-</button>
        <div id="o">
            <input type="number">
            <input type="number">
            <input type="number">
            <input type="number">
            <input type="number">
            <input type="number">
        </div>
        <p>
        Rows: <input type="number" id="r">
        Columns:  <input type="number" id="c">
        </p>
        <script>
            d1 = document.getElementById("d1");
            d2 = document.getElementById("d2");
            o = document.getElementById("o");
            rr = document.getElementById("r");
            cc = document.getElementById("c");
            r = 2;
            c = 3;
            t = r*c;
            function reg(p1, p2, p3) {
                p1.style.width = 100*r+"px";
                p1.style.height = 100*c+"px";
                p1.textContent = '';
                t = r*c;
                for (let i = 1; i <= t; i++) {
                    document.getElementById(p2).innerHTML += "<input type='number' id='"+p3+i+"'>";
                }
            }
            [rr, cc].forEach(function(el) {
                el.addEventListener('keyup', function () {
                    r = rr.value;
                    c = cc.value;
                    reg(d1, "d1", "a");
                    reg(d2, "d2", "b");
                    reg(o, "o", "o");
                });
            });
            function add() {
                let i = 1;
                o.textContent = '';
                for (i = 1; i <= t; i++) {
                    x = 'a'+i;
                    y = 'b'+i; 
                    this["a"+i] = document.getElementById("a"+i).value;
                    this["b"+i] = document.getElementById("b"+i).value;
                    add = parseInt(this[x]) + parseInt(this[y]);
                    document.getElementById("o").innerHTML += "<input type='number' value="+add+">";
                }
            }
            function sub() {
                o.textContent = '';
                for (let i = 1; i <= t; i++) {
                    x = 'a'+i;
                    y = 'b'+i;
                    this["a"+i] = document.getElementById("a"+i).value;
                    this["b"+i] = document.getElementById("b"+i).value;
                    sub = parseInt(this[x]) - parseInt(this[y]);
                    document.getElementById("o").innerHTML += "<input type='number' value="+sub+">";
                }
                i = 1;
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: ALWAYS declare your variables!!!!!! Get a linter installed on your IDE so it yells at you to fix it. lol

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you're over-writing the functions with new values:

```
add = parseInt(this[x]) + parseInt(this[y]);
```

After you re-assign a new value to `add` (and later to `sub`) then that global variable no longer refers to the function.

The lesson here is to use more than one name when referring to multiple things in the code.  For example, you can declare a new variable:

```
let result = parseInt(this[x]) + parseInt(this[y]);
```

(Or any name you want to use *that isn't already used in this context*.)  Then you can use *that* variable when you need to use this numeric value.

Comment: Ohhh that makes a lot of sense! Thank you, it now works :)!